# how to install ssl on glassfish 3.1.2.2

Tags: java, ssl, installation, glassfish-3, keytool

How to install ssl on glassfish 3.1.2.2 ?

I already have certificate for root and intermediate. So certificate is ready.

the problem is how to install it? I already follow guide from http://javadude.wordpress.com/2010/04/06/getting-started-with-glassfish-v3-and-ssl/ and http://eugenedvorkin.com/installing-thawte-certificate-on-glassfish-3-11-server-for-https-traffic/

but still fail , this is what i have tried to do.

1. `keytool -genkeypair -keyalg RSA -keystore keystore.jks -keypass changeit -storepass changeit -alias s1as`
2. `keytool -certreq -alias s1as -file s1as.csr -keystore keystore.jks -storepass changeit`
3. `keytool -import -v -trustcacerts -alias s1as -file root.crt -keystore cacerts.jks -storepass changeit`
4. `keytool -import -v -trustcacerts -alias  Intermediate -file intermediate.crt -keystore cacerts.jks -storepass changeit`

after 4 this step, it will create `keystore.jks` and `cacerts.jks` . After that i copy this 2 files to `glassfish-3.1.2.2\glassfish\domains\domain1\config`

open admin console and set to http listener 2,

- Certificate NickName: keystore
- Key Store: keystore.jks
- Trust Algorithm: sha1
- Max Certificate Length: 5
- Trust Store: cacerts.jks

but when i access https:\ localhost:8181

```
>WARNING: GRIZZLY0007: SSL support could not be configured!
java.io.IOException: sha1 TrustManagerFactory not available
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.net.jsse.JSSE14SocketFactory.init(JSSE14SocketFactory.java:188)
    at com.sun.grizzly.config.SSLConfigHolder.initializeSSL(SSLConfigHolder.java:363)
    at com.sun.grizzly.config.SSLConfigHolder.configureSSL(SSLConfigHolder.java:241)
    at com.sun.grizzly.config.GrizzlyEmbeddedHttps$LazySSLInitializationFilter.execute(GrizzlyEmbeddedHttps.java:202)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

>SEVERE: ProtocolChain exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.grizzly.filter.SSLReadFilter.newSSLEngine(SSLReadFilter.java:352)
    at com.sun.grizzly.filter.SSLReadFilter.obtainSSLEngine(SSLReadFilter.java:399)
    at com.sun.grizzly.filter.SSLReadFilter.execute(SSLReadFilter.java:159)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

>SEVERE: ProtocolChain exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.grizzly.filter.SSLReadFilter.newSSLEngine(SSLReadFilter.java:352)
    at com.sun.grizzly.filter.SSLReadFilter.obtainSSLEngine(SSLReadFilter.java:399)
    at com.sun.grizzly.filter.SSLReadFilter.execute(SSLReadFilter.java:159)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Anyone help me fixing this problem? Thx b4

Answer (score 0):

This configuration works for me:

(on the SSL tab of http-listener-2)

- SSL3 - [enabled]
- TLS - [enabled]
- Client Authentication - [enabled]
- Certificate NickName: s1as
- Key Store: [empty]
- Trust Algorithm: [empty]
- Max Certificate Length: 5
- Trust Store: [empty]
- Cipher Suites: [all selected]

Hope it helps.

Comment: Ok, let's try to spot it. Are you sure you added all the Cipher Suites?(I know it says that all are chosen if none added, but do it manually anyway) What do you have on the General tab of httpp-listener-2?